# To find out the latest time in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365

[image: News paper page release timing]

All I just want to find the maximum/latest time in a time range, I use `MAX` function to find out always, but if the time surpasses midnight(00:00) then it gives result only the maximum time up to 23:59. I need latest time even if surpasses midnight say example 00:50, 01:30 etc Eg I get late output timings like 23:00, 23:30, 23:45, 00:15, 01:30 like this.

kindly help me to get the latest timings

Comment: How do you know if `01:30` is today, tomorrow or yesterday?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So in your example the latest time is 23:45?

Comment: Typeset time
Page 1 23:16
 
Page 2 23:17
 
Page 3 23:15
 
Page 4 23:17
 
Page 5 01:23
 
Page 6 01:05
 
Last page timing 01:23

I get page output timings as above.. and once I get the record I just need to find out last page released time

Comment: @spikey_richie 01:30 is the next day.. so if the output page release timing going beyond 00.00 the next day..it should capture the latest time

Comment: Without date information, or some other information not present in your data, you cannot tell.  In your example, I might assume that the work done in hour `23` occurred prior to the work done in hour `01`.  But, just from the data you present, there is no way to be sure of that. Those same times could represent times on the same day, and it just happens that Pages 5 and 6 were typeset early in the morning, and 1-4 were set late in the evening on the same day. You need to provide some other rule to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

You have some rather unfortunate aspects to the layout of your data and the method of the data's entry. However, that kind of thing is often beyond a spreadsheet writer's control so the question is always "Can it be done with things unchanged, or can it not?" (And "can it not" includes situations in which a viable solution can be found, but fails often enough or subtly enough to cause important problems.)

However, it can be done, though you will have a couple decisions to make to use the below formula. One doesn't seem likely to be an issue, but the other, while it will likely be easy to pick a value for most situations, will still probably create a new "boundary edge" of iffy cases that will arise so will occasionally be a problem unless you think it through and resolve it, in its turn. After a few unhappy events (sigh... the usual path for this, sadly), you'll have some data to help with that.

So, the formula for today's set-up:

```
=LET(Range,  INDEX(B2:B12, SEQUENCE(6,1,1,2), 1),

MAX(IF(Range+1 > MAX(Range) + 3/24, Range, Range+1))
)
```

If you do not have `LET()` available, just replace `Range` with its value in each place it appears and remove the `LET()`-specific portions.

Essentially, the formula takes the values, finds the largest, so the one closest to midnight, and adds a number of hours to it. `3` hours in this case (`3/24`) which can be changed by changing that term's value, or by either changing it to a cell reference that you can set outside the formula, or adding a variable to the `LET()` for easier changing. So, that value is pretty important. I picked "3" out of (maybe) reasonable, but still thin, air. You'd want to consider the idea and pick one that is appropriate. If a print run's parts always begin over 2 hours, 3-4-5, might be good values. If over a longer stretch, well, then higher values seem more reasonable.

Once adjusted, the `MAX()` value is found and all the raw values (not adjusted by the "+3/24") have `1` added to them. `1` because 1 = 24/24, or in other words, one exact full day. These values are compared to the "adjusted by 3 hours max value" found earlier and ones that exceed the adjusted by 3 hours value are assumed to be times that crossed over into the next day (crossed midnight). If so, the "+1" values are passed forward in the formula, and if not, the raw values are passed forward.

Then the `MAX()` of those results is found and that is the latest time.

(The step of adding some hours is done to enable the `IF()` that tests for crossing midnight.)

The formula for `Range` is simply an `INDEX()` function to pull out every other row in the B2:B13 range of the data. It is needed since you have merged cells to deal with causing there to be a blank in every other cell. You can't easily use B2:B13 because the formula's approach would create a bunch of spurious values. With your data set, there would actually be no issues, but what if a page's run began at exactly midnight ("00:00" which is "0" to Excel)? You COULD separate out those, but doing so would be harder than the formula above and doing so but somehow not losing real "0" entries would be even harder. Why not miss out on that ball of worms?

For future improvement, if you can convince the source of entered data that leads to the merging of cells in this part of it to make a change allowing these data to be in normal cells, you could simplify the formula and its understandability. If the time data actually comes from somewhere else and formulas place it here, perhaps you could convince users to allow it to be still in a normal cell with a blank above or below for each two cell set.

The more important improvement to your source material would be the data entry for the times. If those times include date information, then the formula is a simple one function `MAX()` formula. It can still be formatted for display as simple times, not date and time, so look identical to the current display, but be very different.

Excel stores dates as integers and times as decimals. So a date and time is an integral paired with a decimal, 1.045138889 for example. If today were day 45000, then it would be 45000.04513889 and yesterday at 23:15 it would have been 44999.96875. So `MAX()` could easily find the latest of them.

*(And this might be easier than I imply. Your construction in the example suggests these times come from some other source than direct entry. Maybe. But if so, it's very possible they come with date AND time and the date is being stripped off to only leave the time. If so, one could just adjust those formulas to not do that.)*